# React show these div if true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm still new to React and having a hard time trying to figure out how to show div element content if props return true. I know I can only return one render in a function but how can I achieve this. Can I write some type Jsx inline if statement?

```
<div>if true show</div> 
<div>if true show</div> 
<div>false don't show</div> 
<div>if true show</div>
```

Update: I actually used

```
{this.props.test === true &&
    <div>if true show</div>
  }
```

Comment: It is called conditional rendering, and can be read about here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 25):

Simple use case for now.

```
{this.props.test === true &&
    <div>if true show</div>
  }
```

Answer (score 14):

If you're looking for something concise, although not necessarily more readable you can use a ternary operator.

```
{this.props.test ? <div>if true show</div> : ''}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are 2 ways you can achieve what you want:

1) It is a bit verbose, but it permits to easily split your logic in smaller, focused blocks.

```
maybeRenderPerson: function() {
    var personName = ...;
    if ( personName ) {
        return <div className="person">{personName}</div>;
    }
}

render: function() {
    return (
       <div className="component">
          {this.maybeRenderPerson()}
       </div>
    );
}
```

2) This syntax can be quite dangerous if the tested variable can be falsy values like 0,"" or false. Particularly with numbers you should rather modify the test slightly if you want to make sure it renders for 0.

```
render: function() {
    var person= ...; 
    var counter= ...; 
    return (
        <div className="component">
          {person && (
            <Person person={person}/>
         )}
         {(typeof counter !== 'undefined') && (
             <Counter value={counter}/>
         )}
       </div>
    );
}
```

Ass suggested by Matt, you can find more info on conditional rendering [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Comment: Got an error when I added the this keyword (using React with Typescript, so it might be better removing in a similar scenario as mine)

Answer (score 0):

here new exaple for new developer

```
const [ role, setRole ] = useState('');

const onClick = () => setRole('admin');

<input type='button' onClick={onClick} value='i am admin' />

   {role == 'admin' &&
    <div className='admin'>{'this section view using react... '}
      </div>    
  }
```